# Idiomatic way to have conditional form model in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I have a use case where I need to have 3 steps form (customer requirement) that is calling different endpoints for each step, where the first one may have two different schemas - one for private customer, one for company customer.

What is idiomatic way in angular 6 reactive (and possibly dynamic) forms to approach such case?

1. Have dynamically shown and hidden fields with conditional validation depending on select value of customer type.
2. Customer type select value determines if private customer form is rendered or the company customer form is rendered.

The approach nr 1 should work just fine, though half of the fields are different for each case and that leads to a question - wouldn't it be better to have two different forms (with different model bound) for each scenario (approach 2)?

Answer (score 2):

if you have absolutely different fields for **private** and **company** - it might be suitable to use 2 different forms, but if you have similar fields like phone, address, email etc - than it is more suitable to use one form and dynamically hide/show the fields that are different

Comment: yes, though the complexity of validators increase - as all those customer-type specific fields are required and validated. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

There's no right approach for this problem but rather a best approach. Which would be using two different forms. Even better, make it two separated components, and use [`ngSwitch`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgSwitch) to determine which to use isolating the parent component from the responsibility of dealing with the difference between each one.

The positive side of using this approach is that they are different, therefore, it is easier to deal with them separately.

Something like this:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="customerType">
  <private-form *ngSwitchCase="'private'" [(ngModel)]="customer"></private-form>
  <company-form *ngSwitchCase="'company'" [(ngModel)]="customer"></company-form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is going to be the winner from a **readability** point of view as lenilsondc has shown in his answer.
Option 1 is going to be the winner for **maintainability**. If you have fields in common then you'll avoid maintaining them in parallel.

There is also the option to **combine both approaches**. You can abstract the common fields into their own components and include these in both form components.

`private-form`:

```
<app-name-field></app-name-field>
<app-email-field></app-email-field>
<private-specific-field></private-specific-field>
```

`company-form`:

```
<app-name-field></app-name-field>
<app-email-field></app-email-field>
<company-specific-field></company-specific-field>
```